Logging DDL statements from schema.sql in Spring Boot 3
I can't seem to set up logging of DDL statements when schema is generated from schema.sql inside resources folder. I saw similar post here but no help. I'm using Spring Boot 3.3. Here is the yaml file:
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: auth-server
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
  datasource:
    username: user
    password: admin
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/auth_db
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    maximum-pool-size: 10
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
      hibernate.proc.param_null_passing: true
      hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
    hibernate:
      generate-ddl: false
      ddl-auto: none
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
      enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
  jackson:
    deserialization:
      FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES: false

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org:
      springframework:
        transaction: TRACE
        web: DEBUG
        orm.jpa: TRACE
      hibernate:
        engine:
          transaction:
            internal.TransactionImpl:
              TRACE
        SQL:
          TRACE
        orm:
          jdbc:
            bind:
              TRACE

I must have set or not set some property but I cannot see it.
